# Wordpress favorite page full url

Tags: wordpress, save, custom-wordpress-pages, favorites

I have a real estate website with dynamic pages. For example when you click on a property it links to http://example.com/property/?id=23432434.

I want to give users the ability to save a property. I have tried many plugins that offer saving posts but none save the full url and will only save http://example.com/property/.

Does anyone know of a way to implement this? I found $current_url is the full url and I have tried to edit some plugins by changing $postid to this with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code to understand properly. as per your description, you said u generate pages dynamically?  How u generate id? where this `?id=23432434` came from? if this is a random id then how do you uniquely save it as it changes every time. if not then you can use the core PHP function to get that id but that's just a suggestion,  u need to give more details

Comment: @Niraj  Hey, the page is a custom page I created with PHP code that pulls information from a json url.  When you click on a property it links to the page called property but is then populated with information from the json url.

Comment: [link] (http://geekoutaustin.com/live/mls/ ) - here is the page that I'm using